# How can I use trigonometric functions on GPU with Numba?

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, numba

I'm testing `numba.vectorize` with `target='cuda'` and I've run into a problem with using math functions like `numpy.sin` and `numpy.exp` (which are essential to the problem I would like to solve).

Minimal example:

```
@vectorize(["float32(float32)"], target='cuda')
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)
```

When I run this code in a jupyter notebook, it gives me an error, the gist of which appears to be

```
UntypedAttributeError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'sin' of type Module(<module 'numpy' from '/opt/intel/intelpython3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>)
File "<ipython-input-23-6310cdef033e>", line 3
[1] During: typing of get attribute at <ipython-input-23-6310cdef033> (3)
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this not supposed to work?

Comment: Do you have `.py` file (module) named `sin.py`?

Comment: Is - https://stackoverflow.com/q/30427081/2823755 - similar?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. Should I have one?

Comment: It's not really the same issue, as the other question is about JIT-compiling for the CPU. And math functions like np.sin are on the list of supported numpy features in Numba which is referred to in the other answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the [documentation](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html#math), you would see that you need to use functions from the `math` library (or `cmath` library if you are using complex types) within kernels. Numpy math functions are *not* supported in Numba CUDA kernels.